# R: How to use ggplot to plot multiple clusters

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
    df = data.frame(a = rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100))
```

Suppose I wanted to plot df$a and df$b. How can I plot these point clusters on the same graph with different colors?

```
    plot(df$a)
    points(df$b)
```

This is what I want the plot to look like. But how can I do the same thing in ggplot? And make the variables in different colors.

Comment: plot against what? point? boxplot?

Comment: Just point. It should look something like `plot(df$a)` (i.e., a scatterplot), but I want to use ggplot to make everything look prettier. And plot the two columns on the same graph in different colors.

Comment: I'm not a down-voter but you show no research or effort to provide a clear question. You want to plot the data against the index or row number in this particular case.

Comment: Okay, yes I know I'm plotting against the index. But how can I do that with ggplot? That's my question. How can I plot both df$a and df$b on the same plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You''ll have to do two things

1. Create an index for x axis (`plot` does it by defult)
2. melt the data

   ```
   library(ggplot2)
   library(reshape2)
   df$indx <- seq_len(100)
   mdf <- melt(df, "indx")
   ggplot(mdf, aes(indx, value, color = variable)) +
    geom_point()
   ```

   [image]